# Is it possible to set up Stackdriver Monitoring for Kubernetes on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I'm running Kubernetes myself on Google Compute Engine (not Google Container Engine). Google Container Engine has [built-in integration](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/12/monitoring-Container-Engine-with-Google-Cloud-Monitoring.html) with Stackdriver Monitoring and I'm wondering if it's possible to set this up for a Kubernetes cluster on Google Compute Engine.

Specifically, I'd like to see more than just cpu, disk, etc. I want to see Kubernetes data like pod scheduling failures, pod counts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to configure Stackdriver exactly the same way that it is done in GKE.

However, you can set `ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING` to `google` in [config-default.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/config-default.sh#L107) to enable Heapster and Google Cloud Monitoring.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Is there a way to update a running kubernetes cluster to switch from `influxdb` to `google`? I know how to update `config-default.sh` and run `kube-up.sh` to create a new cluster, but not sure how to update one.

Comment: If you change the env var and then run `cluster/gce/upgrade.sh -M` it will upgrade your master, which will rebuild the environment and toggle the value.